# Assistance Required, Developing Java Based Scripting Language?

Tags: java, programming-languages

I have just begun working on a programming language called XScript. It is designed so that I can run it from a Java application, but also re-program it through a java application. The idea being so that I can create virtual computers in games or a program that develops itself over time. So far I have the following code. I understand there may need to be an alteration to the name due to proprietary software, but for now it is fine.

The Artificial Main Class:

```
import com.x.lang.XLoader;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XLoader xl = new XLoader();

        xl.exec("/Users/Nathan/Desktop/XScript/test.xls");
    }
}
```

The XLoader (Loads and executes the XScript):

```
package com.x.lang;

import java.io.File;

import com.x.lang.object.XObject;

public class XLoader {
    XObject xo;
    public String fileLocation;

    public void exec(String fl) {
        fileLocation = fl;

        XObject xo = new XObject(new File(fileLocation));
        xo.exec();
    }
}
```

The XCommandHub Where the Language Key Functions are Stored:

```
package com.x.lang;

import com.x.lang.keyword.Print;
import com.x.lang.keyword.Set;
import com.x.lang.object.XCommand;
import com.x.lang.object.XObject;

public class XCommandHub {
    public XCommand xc[] = new XCommand[2];

    public XCommandHub(XObject x) {
            xc[0] = new Print(x);
        xc[1] = new Set(x);
    }
    public XCommand getCommand(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (xc[i].getCommandName() == s) {
                return xc[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The XCommand Class Defining The Keywords:

```
package com.x.lang.object;

public abstract class XCommand {
    private String commandName;
    public XObject xobject;

    public XCommand (String cn, XObject x) {
        commandName = cn;
        commandName += ": ";
        xobject = x;
    }
    public abstract void exec(XVar xv);

    public String getCommandName() {
        return commandName;
    }
}
```

The XVar Class Defining All Variables:

```
package com.x.lang.object;

public class XVar {
    private String var1;
    public String name;

    public XVar(String s) {
        var1 = s;
    }
    public String getStringValue() {
        if (this.var1 != null) {
            return var1;
        }
        return " ";
    }
    public int getIntValue() {
        if (this.var1 != null) {
            return Integer.parseInt(var1);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }
}
```

The XObject Class Actual Executing the Commands:

```
package com.x.lang.object;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.x.lang.XCommandHub;

public class XObject {
    public XVar xvars[] = new XVar[150];
    public int varCount = 0;
    public File f;
    XCommandHub x;

    public XObject (File file) {
            f = file;
        x = new XCommandHub(this);
    }
    public void addVar(XVar var, String name) {
        xvars[varCount] = var;
        xvars[varCount].setName(name);
        varCount++;
    }
    public XVar getVar(String varName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < varCount; i++) {
            if (xvars[i].name == varName) {
                return xvars[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void exec() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    if (sCurrentLine.startsWith(x.xc[i].getCommandName()))
                    try {
                        x.getCommand(x.xc[i].getCommandName()).exec(new XVar(sCurrentLine.split(": ")[1]));
                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        x.getCommand(x.xc[i].getCommandName()).exec(new XVar(" "));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Two Classes Defining The Commands I Have Programmed So Far:

```
package com.x.lang.keyword;

import com.x.lang.object.XCommand;
import com.x.lang.object.XObject;
import com.x.lang.object.XVar;

public class Print extends XCommand {
    public Print(XObject x) {
        super("print", x);
    }
    @Override
    public void exec(XVar xv) {
        if (xv.getStringValue().startsWith("%")) {
            try {
                System.out.println(xobject.getVar(xv.getStringValue().substring(1)).getStringValue());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println(xv.getStringValue());
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(xv.getStringValue());
        }
    }
}


package com.x.lang.keyword;

import com.x.lang.object.XCommand;
import com.x.lang.object.XObject;
import com.x.lang.object.XVar;

public class Set extends XCommand {
    public Set(XObject x) {
        super("set", x);
    }
    @Override
    public void exec(XVar xv) {
        String[] add = xv.getStringValue().split("=");
        xobject.addVar(new XVar(add[1]), add[0]);
    }
}
```

From what I have programmed so far I have tried to give the user the ability to print a variable that they have declared in the code. A basic .xls (X Language Script) might look something like this:

```
set: x=Hello StackOverflow
print: This was programmed in XScript!
print: 
print: %x
```

However, there is a NullPointerException in the print class when I try and retrieve the variable x from the array. The program returns "%x" rather than "Hello StackOverflow", because I have deliberately caught the exception, however I do not know how it came about in the first place.

Thanks
Doctor_N

Comment: Java has a great debug feature. Use it.

Comment: There is no error in the runtime though. All I know is in the XObject class when it tries to find a matching XVar with name "x" there is an NPE.

Comment: Then you have a `NullPointerException`. In the stacktrace of this error it will give you the name of the class and the line number where the error arised, so look at it with your eyes or **with a debugger** and solve the problem.

Comment: But it has been deliberately caught in case the user was trying to print something that started with a percent sign. I know where the problem is I just don't know why it i occuring

Comment: If you know the exact line on which the NPE is occurring, that would be helpful information, both for you and us.

Comment: @GriffeyDog The NPE is from the XObject class under the getVar(String varName) method. It always returns null for some un-aparent reason.

Comment: @Doctor_N If it is happening in `getVar` method then it is probably in the like `xvars[i].name`. `xvars[i]` is probably `null`. Also `==` is not the way in which you want to compare strings, unless you're comparing references (usually not the case). Another possibility is that the function is returning `null`, and you're calling `.getStringValue()` on it.

Comment: @VivinPaliath thank-you, it was due to me using ==. No-one had ever told me that when I was learning the basics of java.

Comment: @Doctor_N I've provided a detailed answer as to what's going on.

Comment: @Doctor_N Why create another language? You have Clojure, for example, it can do all of what you want.

Comment: @SargeBorsch It could just be an academic exercise. When I was a wee lad in my freshman year of college (oh so many years ago), I decided to write my own language without known anything about recursive descent parsers, BNF's, EBNF's, or anything. The code was horrible and only worked *most* of the time. Ultimately nothing came of it, but I did learn a lot!

Comment: @VivinPalith yeah, I am only 14 and I though it would teach me a lot about how the actual language work. www.indiedb.com/games/kaput/ and I want to put virtual computers in that game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will never find the variable it is looking for:

```
public XVar getVar(String varName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < varCount; i++) {
        if (xvars[i].name == varName) {
            return xvars[i];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This function will *almost always* return `null` since you are comparing strings using `==` and not using `.equals`. `==` compares references (memory addresses) and it is highly unlikely that the parameter and the string you are comparing against will point to the same location. Due to this, you *almost always* return `null`.

Because of that, this line will always cause a `NullPointerException`:

```
System.out.println(xobject.getVar(xv.getStringValue().substring(1)).getStringValue());
```

This is because you are effectively calling `getStringValue()` on `null`.

I suggest changing the `if` to:

```
if(xvars[i] != null && xvars[i].name.equals(varName)) {
    ...
}
```